# Metro-style application UI design: Pages vs Scenarios

Tags: c#, mvvm, microsoft-metro

I'm working on a windows 8 metro-style app, using developer preview for an academic project at university. We have to use MVVM pattern.

In the main Page we have a metro-style main menu with buttons. Each button leads to an application facility (ie. 'Show my Library', 'Show Favourites', ...) which should belong to a different View, according to MVVM pattern.

In your opinion should we create a new 'metro-style Page' for each View or expect a 'Scenario' for each [use case](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Use_case_diagram) refreshing the main Page, like those present in many example apps?
In other terms, using MVVM should there be a 1:1 match between 'plain old WPF Windows' and 'brand new metro-style Pages'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The thing with MVVM is that there are no hard rules as to what constitutes a View other than the fact that it is the means by which the user can view the ViewModel data.

A View need not be a Page, but can be a Control. Thus you can have one page, on which many View controls are displayed, if you wish. Quite often I have my Views as controls, even if they are to be the sole item displayed on a page, as it allows me to embed them in other pages more easily at a later date.

The MVVM pattern is purely a means of separating the UI from the business/code logic. A ViewModel class doesn't care how it's data is displayed, it just provides the binding points, properties etc., for the data to be displayed and trigger points for code function.

Some people will insist that there is never any code in the code behind files, but I think that a more pragmatic approach is required. Code that controls visual aspects of the View is fine, and there are occaisions when what appears to be business logic intrudes.

For example when implementing drag and drop functionality code will be required in the code behind. This is really just a visual aspect so no problem there, but if the business model dictates that only certain items, or a maximum number of items are dropped in a given location then the ViewModel will need to provide some data binding points that the View can use to implement this. By doing so you could argue that the View code behind now implements some business logic.

So back to your original question. I would try to implement the application such that it behaves as is expected for a windows 8 metro-stryle application. This will obviously have a bearing on how you code, but it should still be possible to stick to the MVVM pattern when doing so.

Comment: +1 for the "pragmatic approach". You're right, it's not a matter of phylosophy...